# ASP.NET Core 3.1 : how to route to a controller in a sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

How can I set up a default routing if the controller is inside a subfolder? Currently, running the code shown here, I get an error

> localhost page can't be found

My folder structure is set up like this:

```
Project Name    
    > API
        > Controllers   
            > ProductsController
```

ProductsController

```
[Area("API")]
[Route("products")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("list")]
    public ActionResult<List<Product>> GetProductsList()
    {
        var products = _context.Products.ToList();
        return Ok(products);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "MyProducts",
    areaName: "API",
    pattern: "{controller=products}/{action=list}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[Route("products")]` in your code will cause the controller to be available at URL `/products` instead of `/api/products`

To fix change it to `[Route("[area]/[controller]")]` or `[Route("api/products")]`.

Edit: By the way, the folder structure of your C# files in your project has no effect in runtime, since they all get compiled in a DLL. So you can layout the C# files the way you see logical without worrying about runtime effects.